# Different functions to print a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I saw two (different?) implementations of a function to print a linked list. Let me first give my code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
        int x;
        struct node *next;
};

void free_list(struct node *current);
void print_list_a(struct node *current);
void print_list_b(struct node *head);

int main()
{
        struct node *head;
        struct node *second;
        struct node *third;
        head = NULL;
        second = NULL;
        third = NULL;

        head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if (!head) {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        second = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if (!second) {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        third = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        if (!third) {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        head->x = 1;
        head->next = second;

        second->x = 2;
        second->next = third;

        third->x = 3;
        third->next = NULL;

        print_list_a(head);
        print_list_b(head);

        free_list(head);

        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Above I have declared two print functions `print_list_a()` and `print_list_b()`. Their definitions look like this:

```
void print_list_a(struct node *current)
{
        while (current != NULL) {
                printf("%d->", current->x);
                current = current->next;
        }
}

void print_list_b(struct node *head)
{
        struct node *current;

        current = head;
        while (current != NULL) {
                printf("%d->", current->x);
                current = current->next;
        }
{
```

My questions are: a) Is there any real difference between `print_list_a()` and `print_list_b()`? and b) Is there an advantage of one over the other aka which is to be preferred? I am a bit confused as both achieve the same. The only advantage for `print_list_b()` I can see is that `head` appears in the functions parameter list.

Comment: there is no difference in your methods except that you use a local variable which is useful when the function has side effects .Here it does not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between the functions. The both uses a local variable that to store the current node in the list. Take into account that function parameters are also local variables of the function.

Nevertheless as for me I would prefer the following definition of the function

```
void print_list_b( const struct node *head )
{
    for ( const struct node *current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d->", current->x );
    }
}
```

Or the following

```
void print_list_b( const struct node *current )
{
    for ( ; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf( "%d->", current->x );
    }
}
```

But I would use the for loop.:)

Take into account that the compiler can generate the same object code for the all loops: while or for.:)

I suggest you to consider one more print_list functions.:)

```
void print_list( const struct node *current )
{
    if ( current != NULL )
    {
        printf( "%d->", current->x ); print_list( current->next );
    }
}

void print_list( const struct node *current )
{
    if ( current != NULL )
    {
        print_list( current->next ); printf( "%d->", current->x ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: The classic recursive solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

They do the exact same thing. 
Print the list till null is encountered.

One starts directly from the passed parameter, while the other one unnecessarily creates a node object, assigns it to the parameter, and then iterates it through the list.